# How do I maximise my potion result in Two Worlds?

Tags: two-worlds

I'm experimenting with alchemy in Two Worlds, making permanent affect potions. What methods or strategies should I consider to maximise the effectiveness of my potions?

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple links that may help:
[Alchemy Basics](http://twoworldsvault.ign.com/View.php?view=Guides.Detail&id=1) This also has a link to a list of ingredients and what they do.
[The Ultimate Manual](http://insidetwoworlds.com/showthread.php?t=27080) This is a pretty good in general guide to everything in Two Worlds.
and 
[Recipes](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/forum/showthread.php?t=36876) Not a comprehensive list but contains an answer to your question Quoted here:

> First off, it's useful to have your
>   Alchemy skill at 10 (there's a trainer
>   in Rovant Village, west of Tharbakin,
>   to get you started), as this derives
>   the most beneficial results in your
>   end products. Second, if you've fooled
>   around with the system at all, it
>   seems to give the best results to use
>   10 (the maximum allowed to make one
>   potion) items, meaning you're using
>   several of certain of the items.
>   Third, it seems the key is to use more
>   non-mineral items in your formulation
>   (things derived from plants and
>   animals, such as beaver fat or
>   lavender, or even health or mana
>   restoring potions, as filler) than
>   mineral items (such as diamonds or
>   rubies) in order to make permanent
>   potions (and, since the permanent
>   stat-increasing potions are probably
>   most useful, those are the ultimate
>   goal). And, since we want to use ten
>   items to get the best results, that
>   means 4 minerals, and 6 non-minerals
>   (obviously).

Comment: Use only permanent effects for permanent potions.