# Brewing Minerals with the Alchemy skill

Tags: two-worlds

In general, Alchemy in *Two Worlds* involves mixing two items and you get a result that combines the ingredients. However, when I try brewing using one of the mineral items that yield permanent bonuses (Magnesite, Silver, Salt, Ruby, etc), I am getting damage gems instead. Is there a trick to this that I am missing?

Comment: Similar to https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/698/how-do-i-maximise-my-potion-result-in-two-worlds, and the answer draws from the same source, but they were looking at maximizing and I was looking at just figuring out how to get a potion from the minerals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And, with a bit more searching, I found [a thread where the alchemy system is broken down](https://web.archive.org/web/20130109131250/http://www.xbox360achievements.org/forum/showthread.php?t=36876) and what I was missing was that permanent potions require more organic than non-organic materials. Otherwise, you wind up with traps and damage gems.

> First off, it's useful to have your Alchemy skill at 10 (there's a trainer in Rovant Village, west of Tharbakin, to get you started), as this derives the most beneficial results in your end products. Second, if you've fooled around with the system at all, it seems to give the best results to use 10 (the maximum allowed to make one potion) items, meaning you're using several of certain of the items. Third, it seems the key is to use more non-mineral items in your formulation (things derived from plants and animals, such as beaver fat or lavender, or even health or mana restoring potions, as filler) than mineral items (such as diamonds or rubies) in order to make permanent potions (and, since the permanent stat-increasing potions are probably most useful, those are the ultimate goal). And, since we want to use ten items to get the best results, that means 4 minerals, and 6 non-minerals (obviously).